# Syntax difference in jQuery document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a difference in doing

`$(document).ready(myFunction);`

and

`$(document).ready(myFunction());`?

Comment: If it helps, the same difference as between `foo(bar)` and `foo(bar())`.

Comment: You could also use the shortcut method `$(function() { //code });` which is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { //code });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Big difference - `$(document).ready(myFunction());` will call the function immediately, and use the return value as the `ready` handler. `$(document).ready(myFunction);` will use `myFunction` as the handler.

Some clarification:

`$(document).ready(myFunction);` is the **proper** way to do it. This sets the function `myFunction` as the *handler* for the ready event - the function that will be executed when the event happens.

In 99% of cases, `$(document).ready(myFunction());` is the **wrong** way to do it. What happens here is that `myFunction` is called immediately, *not* when the ready event occurs. If `myFunction()` returns a *function*, that returned function will be used as the event handler. However, this is a more advanced usage, and requires knowledge of closures and first-class functions.

Comment: Ok. Great, can you provide any resource about ready handler.It will be more helpfull.Thanks

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar You could read the [jQuery documentation for `ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @Scimonster. Thanks, actually it would be better if you can post in jsfiddle with the difference.
Actually I have try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisek101088/bkbzjad1/).And can't understand the difference. Please don't mind if it sounds stupid.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar Your fiddle doesn't really show anything, you'd need a different example to really see the difference. If you have more questions, i suggest you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: what do you mean by `myFunction as the handler` ,please explain.

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar I've edited the answer to clarify some jargon.